# Single bluetooth keyboard on multiple computers?

Tags: 13.04, keyboard, bluetooth

Is it possible to use a single bluetooth keyboard on multiple computers (not simultaneously)??

IE: I have two laptops (from the company and my own) and every time I try to switch between them, I need first to remove the keyboard and reconnect (re add). Otherwise it woun't work.

Looks like once the connection is made, the keyboard works only with that specific laptop. And if I try to change to the other computer I need to recognize the keyboard again.

PS: synergy is not an option for me since it requires a client / server connection.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common Bluetooth security feature to prevent from connecting to more than one device. Unless your Bluetooth keyboard is able to store more than one connection there is not much we can do about this.

Also see [Bluetooth pairing and security on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Pairing_and_bonding).